# RactiveJS Should Target The Element Triggering Proxy Event, Not It's Children

Tags: javascript, dom-events, ractivejs

I'm trying to add an `active` classname to the `li` that is clicked on. Showing that it's selected.

My template:

```
 var legCatagoryTemplate = "<ul>{{#legs:i}}<li><a href='#' on-click='selectCategory:{{this}},{{i}}' data-id='{{i}}'><figure><div class='imgWrapper'><img src='{{preview}}'></div><figcaption><h4>{{name}}</h4><p>W: {{width}}&quot;  H:<span></span>: {{material}}</p></figcaption></figure></a></li>{{/legs}}</ul>";
```

How its called:

```
var legCategoryView = new Ractive({
        el: "#catalog",
        template: legCatagoryTemplate,
        data: response_from_ajax
    });
```

How I'm handling the event:

```
legCategoryView.on('selectCategory', function ( event, self, index ){
    console.log(event.target, self, index);
}
```

What I've found:

`event.target` is the element inside of the `a` that was clicked (eg `div.imgwrapper`, `figcaption`)

Non Ractive behaves similarly: [click event on a div should not be triggered by it's children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389845/click-event-on-a-div-should-not-be-triggered-by-its-children)

What is a good solution to targeting the element with the on-click proxy object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might just traverse the DOM and find the `li` element but that can cause troubles in certain situations. If you call `ractive.set('legs', new_data)`, Ractive will reuse the existing nodes, so your class will remain there. There are several solutions for this problem (the third is probably the best):

1. Use `ractive.merge()` instead of `ractive.set()`.
2. Use `splice()` and `push()` instead of `ractive.set()`.
3. Change your template and let Ractive manage the class:

```
<ul>
{{#legs:i}}
    <li class="{{#.active }}active{{/}}">
        <a href='#' on-click='selectCategory:{{this}},{{i}}' data-id='{{i}}'>
            <figure>
                <div class='imgWrapper'><img src='{{preview}}'></div>
                <figcaption>
                    <h4>{{name}}</h4>

                    <p>W: {{width}}&quot; H:<span></span>: {{material}}</p>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </a>
     </li>
{{/legs}}
</ul>
```

```
ractive.on('selectCategory', function ( e ) {
    ractive.set(e.keypath + '.active', true);
});
```

Comment: Can you explain what `<li class="{{#.active}}active{{/}}">` does? I'm not familiar with that usage. Is that what `set(e.keypath + '.active')` is referring to? 

Since its a list of selectable items, When a new item is clicked I want the currently active `li` to have it's active class removed before adding the active class to the current one, and trigger a function to do stuff related to the newly activated item.

Comment: @Cmndo use this instead: `<li class="{{#i===active}}active{{/}}">`, then just set a single active property based on the indexRef of the event: `set('active', e.indexRef.i)`

Comment: Sorry, that should just be `index`, not `indexRef`: `set('active', e.index.i)`

Comment: @martypdx Very interesting. `#i====active` is awesome. What is that called/Where can I find everything there is to know about what's allowed?

Comment: Attribute values take mustache refs (including partials!) just like anywhere else in the template (it can be just part of the attribute: `class="myclass {{#condition}}otherclass{{/}}"`). [Ractive adds expressions](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/expressions) to mustache, so you can do things like comparing the current index to the active index, aka `{{# (i===active) }}`. [See here](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/mustaches) for more on "blocks" in mustache. The example I gave is an implicit conditional block, Ractive allows explicit as well, which would be: `{{#if i===active}}active{{/if}}`

Comment: @Cmndo `set(e.keypath + '.active')` will set `active` property on the clicked object to `true`. `<li class="{{#.active}}active{{/}}">` will check if there is such property and add `active` class if yes. The difference between mine and @martypdx's solution is that mine supports multiple active items at once. If you need to have only one active item then his solution is better.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the idea of using jQuery to traverse up the dom with  `$.closest()` like this

```
legCategoryView.on('selectCategory', function ( event, self, index ){
    $(event.original.target).closest('li').addClass("active");
}
```

That works actually.